# How to deserialize/serialize Azure Service Bus using spring.cloud in Java

Tags: java, azure, deserialization, azureservicebus

I am using spring.cloud to connect to Azure Service Bus in Java. Here is maven dependency I am using:

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.azure.spring</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-cloud-azure-starter-integration-servicebus</artifactId>
        <version>4.5.0</version>
    </dependency>
```

I am able to consume the message from the queue as byte array and it converts the message to string. Here is my main code after receiving a message from queue:

```
@ServiceActivator(inputChannel = INPUT_CHANNEL)
public void messageReceiver(byte[] payload, @Header(AzureHeaders.CHECKPOINTER) Checkpointer checkpointer) {
        String message = new String(payload);
        LOGGER.info("New message received: '{}'", message);
        checkpointer.success()
                .doOnSuccess(s -> LOGGER.info("Message '{}' successfully checkpointed", message))
                .doOnError(e -> LOGGER.error("Error found", e))
                .block();
    }
```

And here is my example data in JSON as short version:

```
{
    "serverId": 123,
    "message": "{some message}"
}
```

What I would like to do is to create a Java object like this:

```
public class ExampleMessage {
    private final Integer serverId;
    private final String message;
```

and when a message from queue is consumed, it will convert the message to my Java object. I am used to using DataTypeProvider in order to use custom Java object for AMQP message consumption which will convert and validate the conversion behind the scene. Does spring.cloud.azure has built-in method/functionality for deserialization? or Do I manually deserialize and do validation for a consumed message?

Answer (score 0):

- Here I was able to convert the Json object to java object using [Gson](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.google.code.gson/gson) class.
- I am just reading a message from the service bus and converting it to java object.

my pom.xml (dependencies)

```
<dependency>  
 <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>  
 <artifactId>spring-boot-starter</artifactId>  
</dependency>  
  
<dependency>  
 <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>  
 <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>  
 <scope>test</scope>  
</dependency>  
<dependency>  
 <groupId>com.google.code.gson</groupId>  
 <artifactId>gson</artifactId>  
 <version>2.8.6</version>  
</dependency>  
<dependency>  
 <groupId>com.azure</groupId>  
 <artifactId>azure-messaging-servicebus</artifactId>  
 <version>7.0.0</version>  
</dependency>  
<!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/io.projectreactor/reactor-core -->  
<dependency>  
 <groupId>io.projectreactor</groupId>  
 <artifactId>reactor-core</artifactId>  
 <version>3.3.11.RELEASE</version>  
</dependency>
```

My test class :

```
public class TestClass {  
    public String name ;  
 public int version;  
  TestClass(String n , int v)  
    {  
        this.name = n ;  
 this.version = v ;  
  }  
}
```

The main class :

```
@SpringBootApplication  
public class ServicebustestApplication {  
  
   public static void main(String[] args) throws InterruptedException {  
  
  
      SpringApplication.run(ServicebustestApplication.class, args);  
  String  conn = " Endpoint=sb://v-mganorkarjsonobject.servicebus.windows.net/;SharedAccessKeyName=RootManageSharedAccessKey;SharedAccessKey=HglLVGlgMsYZGQMOtUfp4g2oka1CpCbVR0YEHgly7jA= ";  
  
  CountDownLatch countdownLatch1 = new CountDownLatch(1);  
  ServiceBusProcessorClient processorClient = new ServiceBusClientBuilder()  
            .connectionString("<Your COnnection String >")  
            .processor()  
            .queueName("test")  
            .processMessage(ServicebustestApplication::processMessage)  
            .processError(context -> processError(context,countdownLatch1))  
            .buildProcessorClient();  
  
  processorClient.start();  
  TimeUnit.SECONDS.sleep(10);  
  processorClient.close();  
  
  
  }  
  
   private static void processMessage(ServiceBusReceivedMessageContext context) {  
   
  ServiceBusReceivedMessage message = context.getMessage();  
  
  System.out.printf("Processing message. Session: %s, Sequence #: %s. Contents: %s%n", message.getMessageId(),  
  message.getSequenceNumber(), message.getBody());  
  
  Gson gson = new Gson();  
  
  TestClass testobject = gson.fromJson(String.valueOf(message.getBody()),TestClass.class);  
  
  System.out.println("name: "+testobject.name +" version: "+ testobject.version+"");  
  }  



   private static void processError(ServiceBusErrorContext context, CountDownLatch countdownLatch) {  
   
  }  
}
```

Here the callback to process message will process the message and then we can use the GSON to convert the json string to java object.

```
  Gson gson = new Gson();  
  
  TestClass testobject = gson.fromJson(String.valueOf(message.getBody()),TestClass.class);
```

output of the code :

[image]

Comment: Is it possible to get header or custom properties from the json?